# Modifying my query for concatenation C#

Tags: c#, mysql, drop-down-menu, concatenation

I have a table in my database with 4 column that are `Specie` | `Price` | `Stock` | `Country`.

I have a drop down list called `ddlcountry` that is populated via the `Country` column.

I then have a drop down called  `DdPetPist` that should be populated with all `Specie` associated with the country chosen via the previous drop down.

For example I choose UK and I have a list Dog, Cat and rabbit.

**Problem's**

1. At the moment I chose UK and all Specie show on the second drop down.
2. When I select the country drop down it repeats the country more than once.

**Code for first drop down (country selection)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MySqlCommand cd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Animals", cs); // need to make it so changes database
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader ddlCountry = cd2.ExecuteReader();
            ddlcountry.DataSource = ddlCountry;
            ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Country";
            ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
            ddlcountry.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Code to populate second list On Select of county**

```
protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlcountry.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Animals", ddlcountry.Text), cs);
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
            DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
            DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
            DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
            DdPetPist.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I think I am close just not sure how to adjust my Query s appropriately.
any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Animals` where you populate your country-ddl? Apart from that, don't reuse your `MySqlConnection` but use the `using`-statement. I'm suprised that you don't get an exception since you are disposing it. If you's use it in another method afterwards you would get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: do you mean that is causing me problems ?

Comment: I think you should not always fetch the species over and over again from your database.
Rather load them once (also in the page_load) and then depending on what you select, you change your list accordingly.

Comment: Some tipps: use 'using' statement for disposable resources, e.g. 'MySqlCommand' and 'SqlDbConnection' is disposable.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advise I will try and change some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `WHERE` Clause for the specific Country selected is missing in your Query in the `ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged` event. Change it like below. I parameterized the query as pointed out by @Fabian to prevent SQL Injection attacks. Also like others have suggested, you should use the `Using` syntax to automatically dispose the connection when it goes out of scope.

```
private String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(Specie) FROM Animals WHERE Country = @SelectedCountry;";
MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(sql), cs);
cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedCountry", ddlcountry.Text);
MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
DdPetPist.DataBind();
```

Also, in your 1st query, no need to select everything with *. Update it as follows to get UNIQUE Country values.

```
MySqlCommand cd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Country) FROM Animals", cs);
```

Comment: Please provide parameterized solution to get +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the problem.

Just Replace

`MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Animals",ddlCountry.Text),cs);`

with

`MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT Animals.Specie FROM Animals WHERE Animals.Country={0};",ddlCountry.Text),cs);`

The outuput will be a data table with only one column(Specie)

Comment: Please provide parameterized solution to get +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your query for country dropdown to

```
"SELECT Distinct Country FROM Animals"
```

and your query for the second dropdown to

```
string.Format("SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE Country = '{0}'", ddlcountry.Text)
```

Comment: Please provide parameterized solution to get +1. :)